# Dynamically compile files in depending of #define

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a project Application, and in this project I have two folders "behavior1" and "behaviour2"

```
Application
|_ behaviour1
| |_ action
|   |_ action.h
|   |_ action.cpp
|
|_ behaviour2
| |_ action
|   |_ action.h
|   |_ action.cpp
|
|_ behaviour_type.h
|_ app.cpp
```

Where action.h in each directory define a derived class from the abstract class

```
class AbstractAction {
   public:
       virtual ~AbstractAction() = default;
       virtual void Execute() = 0;
}
```

But implementations are different.

Then by using the next code in the file "behaviour_type.h"

```
#define CURRENT_BEHAVIOUR bevahiour1
#define QUOTEME_1(x) #x
#define QUOTEME(x) QUOTEME_1(x) 
#define INCLUDE_FILE(x) QUOTEME(CURRENT_BEHAVIOUR/x)
```

in the "app.cpp" I can write

```
#include "behavior_type.h"
#include INCLUDE_FILE(hook/action.h)
...
AbstractAction* action = new Action();
action->Execute();
```

But in this situation two "action.h"s (from behavior1 and behavior2) will be compiled. And I want to compile only one, which I included. Can it be possible
compile only one "action.h" file using only the source code (i.e. my INCLUDE_FILE directive), not compiler properties.

May be this question is silly, excuse me, but I am a newbie here.
Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like an unmaintainable approach. Why not just make two different classes? Then use something like a "strategy pattern" to pick the right class?

Comment: You wan't interfaces and a `Factory` class (or function).

Comment: It might be easier to specify what to build using a build tool: QMake, CMake, or plain old Make.

Comment: @CoryKramer: guessing here, one reason might be that behavior1 & behavior2 are platform- or library-specific, i.e., only one of them can be compiled in a given env.

Comment: Conditional compilation should really only be used to target different platforms (e.g. Linux v. Windows)

Comment: Thanks all. Yes it is not a good solution, but is it somewhat like a legacy project, and I can't change its architecture.

Comment: Now I decided to use different build configurations for each "behavior"  and in each configuration exclude unnecessary files (Project -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Exclude from build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your macros do or are supposed to achieve, but why not use the simple variant:

```
#ifdef ACTION_1
    #include "behaviour1/hook/action.h"
#else
    #include "behaviour2/hook/action.h"
#endif

AbstractAction* action = new Action();
action->Execute();
```

That said, I fully support the comments that said you should have both and use some kind of pattern instead of conditional compilation.

Comment: As I sad earlier,  I decided to use different build configurations for each "behavior" and in each configuration exclude unnecessary files (Project -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Exclude from build), But nevertheless thank you very much.